# No javascript provider is configured

Tags: grails, grails-2.2

**Update:**  I've isolated this error to registering the onchange event in this select. If I remove the onchange, the page renders without error, otherwise I get the **No javascript provider** error.

```
<g:select optionKey="id" optionValue="name" name="course" id="course"
   from="${com.TourneyCard.Course.list(sort:'name')}" value="${homeCourse.id}"
   onchange="${remoteFunction(controller:'foursome', action:'ajaxGetTeesJSON',
     params:'\'id=\' + escape(this.value)', 
     onSuccess:'updateTees(data);')}">
</g:select>
```

For various reasons I'd like to include jQuery using the resources Plugin instead of the the jQuery Plugin. It's mostly working but I have a page that will not render and is instead issuing the error **No javascript provider is configured**.

My ApplicationResources.groovy defines jquery:

```
jquery {
    resource url: 'js/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js', disposition: 'head'
}
```

My main.gsp layout looks like this:

```
<head>
    <g:layoutHead/>
    <g:javascript library="jquery"/>
    <r:require module="jquerymobile"/>
    <r:layoutResources />
</head>
```

The page issuing the provider not configured error looks like this:

```
<head>
    <meta content="main" name="layout">
    <r:require modules="jqmdatebox,jqmgrid960,updateTees"/>
    ....
</head>
<body>
    ....
    <g:javascript>
        var zselect = document.getElementById('tee')
        var zopt = zselect.options[zselect.selectedIndex]
    </g:javascript>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're manually setting the JQuery resource, there's no need to set:

```
<g:javascript library="jquery"/>
```

Instead, just require your module:

```
<r:requires module="jquery, jquerymobile"/>
```

**EDIT**

Looking at your new info, I think that your issue is with the `remoteFunction` method. Since it needs to know which javascript library you're using. Try adding `<g:setProvider library="jquery"/>` to your page.

Comment: Thanks, I made that change but there's no change in the results. The one page still has a problem and the others continue to work

Comment: hibernate, joda-time, famfamfam, resources, tomcat, spring-security-core, spring-security-ui, export, webxml, mail, cloud-foundry

Comment: So jqmdatebox, jqmgrid960 are just modules that you created?

Comment: Yes. It looks like it has to do with the updateTees module of mine. Maybe it isn't loading or the reference to the updateTees function has changed in some way. This is a function tied to an onChange event in a select. If I comment out the select with the updateTees call, the page loads fine.

Comment: I've isolated this error to registering the onchange event in this select. If I remove the onchange, the page renders without error, otherwise I get the No javascript provider error.

    <g:select optionKey="id" optionValue="name" name="course" id="course" from="${com.TourneyCard.Course.list(sort:'name')}" value="${homeCourse.id}"
    onchange="${remoteFunction(controller:'foursome', action:'ajaxGetTeesJSON', params:'\'id=\' + escape(this.value)', onSuccess:'updateTees(data);')}">
    </g:select>

Comment: It's the remoteFunction call within the onchange....  Does that mean the runtime can determine which javascript library to use when the remoteFunction is loaded?  The error is happening when the Select is rendered, not when the onchange event occurs.

Comment: @SeattleStephens See my edit. I think that your issue is with [remoteFunction](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html)

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved the same error what was caused from a *g:remoteLink* tag.  I found that I need to call   twice.  Once in the head, and the other in the footer where you should be loading js files from.  I also had to add jQuery as a plugin in BuildConfig.groovy

```
plugins {
    runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
    runtime ':resources:1.2'
    ...
}
```

My main.gsp has

```
  <r:require modules="app, jquery" />
  <g:setProvider library="jquery" />
  <r:layoutResources/>
  <g:layoutHead />
```

I have g:layoutHead last so jQuery loads before scripts that may need it.

If you are just inline some scripts you may want to look at

- http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/javascript.html

*If you use this tag to render inline JavaScript code, it is recommended that you use the Resources plugin's  tag to produce inline script that is included at the end of the body, or in the head if necessary - rather than inline. For more control use the Resources plugin's  tag directly.* -

- http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/ref/Tags/script.html

Answer (score 0):

try to put

```
grails.views.javascript.library = "jquery"
```

into Config.groovy or insert into main layout:

```
<g:setProvider library="jquery"/>
```

Comment: setting the library in Config.groovy had no effect but using the g:setProvider in the layout gets rid of the No javascript provider error but now that page displays the message **Resources are being processed, please wait...**

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

Add the following class (from the jquery Grails plugin) to your application

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.JavascriptProvider

class JQueryProvider implements JavascriptProvider {

    /**
     * doRemoteFunction creates a jQuery-AJAX-Call
     *
     * @param taglib
     * @param attrs
     * @param out
     *
     * @return the jQuery-like formatted code for an AJAX-request
     */
    def doRemoteFunction(taglib, attrs, out) {
        // Optional, onLoad
        if (attrs.onLoading) {
            out << "${attrs.onLoading};"
        }

        // Start ajax
        out << /jQuery.ajax({/

        // Method
        def method = (attrs.method ? attrs.remove('method') : 'POST')
        out << "type:'$method'"

        // Optional, synchron call
        if ("false" == attrs.asynchronous) {
            out << ",async:false"
            attrs.remove('asynchronous')
        }

        // Optional, dataType to use
        if (attrs.dataType) {
            out << ",dataType:'${attrs.remove('dataType')}'"
        }

        // Additional attributes
        if (attrs.params || attrs.jsParams) {
            if (!(attrs?.params instanceof Map)) {
                // tags like remoteField don't deliver a map
                out << ",data:${attrs.remove('params')}"
            } else {
                out << ",data:{"

                boolean hasParams = false

                if (attrs?.params instanceof Map) {
                    hasParams = true
                    out << attrs.remove('params').collect { k, v ->
                        "\'" +
                                "${k}".encodeAsJavaScript() +
                                "\': \'" +
                                "${v}".encodeAsJavaScript() +
                                "\'"
                    }.join(",")
                }

                if (attrs?.jsParams instanceof Map) {
                    if (hasParams) {
                        out << ","
                    }

                    out << attrs.remove('jsParams').collect { k, v ->
                        "\'" +
                                "${k}".encodeAsJavaScript() +
                                "\': \'" +
                                "${v}".encodeAsJavaScript() +
                                "\'"
                    }.join(",")
                }

                out << "}"
            }
        }

        // build url
        def url = attrs.url ? taglib.createLink(attrs.remove('url')) : taglib.createLink(attrs);
        out << ", url:'${url}'"

        // Add callback
        buildCallback(attrs, out)

        // find all onX callback events
        def callbacks = attrs.findAll { k, v ->
            k ==~ /on(\p{Upper}|\d){1}\w+/
        }

        // remove all onX callback events
        callbacks.each { k, v ->
            attrs.remove(k)
        }

        out << "});"

        // Yeah, I know, return is not needed, but I like it
        return out
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to create callback object
     *
     * @param attrs Attributes to use for the callback
     * @param out Variable to attache the output
     */
    def buildCallback(attrs, out) {
        // TODO check for strlen
        if (out) {
            out << ','
        }

        //*** success
        out << 'success:function(data,textStatus){'

        if (attrs.onLoaded) {
            out << "${attrs.onLoaded};"
        }

        if (attrs.update instanceof Map) {
            if (attrs.update?.success) {
                out << "jQuery('#${attrs.update.success}').html(data);"
            }
        } else if (attrs.update) {
            out << "jQuery('#${attrs.update}').html(data);"
        }

        if (attrs.onSuccess) {
            out << "${attrs.onSuccess};"
        }

        out << '}'

        //*** failure
        out << ',error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){'

        if (attrs.update instanceof Map) {
            if (attrs.update?.failure) {
                // Applied to GRAILSPLUGINS-1919
                out << "jQuery('#${attrs.update?.failure}').html(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);"
            }
        }

        if (attrs.onFailure) {
            out << "${attrs.onFailure};"
        }

        out << '}'

        if (attrs.onComplete) {
            out << ",complete:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus){${attrs.onComplete}}"
        }
    }

    /**
     * Serializes the surrounding form.
     *
     * @param attrs attrs.params to serialize
     */
    def prepareAjaxForm(attrs) {
        // Fix for http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS-1865
        if (attrs.forSubmitTag) {
            attrs.params = "jQuery(this).parents('form:first').serialize()".toString()
        }
        else {
            attrs.params = "jQuery(this).serialize()".toString()
        }
    }
}
```

Register this class as the provider (for AJAX GSP tags) in `Bootstrap.groovy`

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.JavascriptTagLib

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->    
        JavascriptTagLib.PROVIDER_MAPPINGS.jquery = JQueryProvider
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This link was very useful and shows what steps you might need to take.
https://grails.org/plugin/jquery

Edit:
Using the above website I got mine to wrok by doing this:

1. put this in config.groovy: grails.views.javascript.library = "jquery"
2. put this ins buildConfig.groovy runtime "org.grails.plugins:jquery:1.11.1"
3. note(someone suggested another plugin and it actually broke mine)
4. I didn't need to do anything else (I removed the g:javascript tag completely) and it just worked.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).